# Ethereum Tries - Concise Summary

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, storage-trie

I am looking for a comprehensive summary of the keys and values used in each of the tries in Ethereum.

[Ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/patricia-merkle-trie/) makes a good attempt at this, but I will try and clarify some aspects that are unclear for me here.

For those curious, the best explanation of tries in Ethereum I have personally found are:

- https://easythereentropy.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/understanding-the-ethereum-trie/
- https://medium.com/shyft-network/understanding-trie-databases-in-ethereum-9f03d2c3325d
- https://medium.com/cybermiles/diving-into-ethereums-world-state-c893102030ed
- https://rockwaterweb.com/ethereum-merkle-patricia-trees-javascript-tutorial/

However these mostly go into depth on the general structure, or the state Trie, and don't summarize the other tries well.

For each of the following tries, I understand they are represented in a (separate?) leveldb (or otherwise), that is also key/value:

```
  key = keccak256(rlp(node))
  value = rlp(node)     //where rlp(node) == rlp([HP(node_key), node_value])
```

Below is my summarized understanding of each trie, please correct me if this is wrong in any way, and if so why.

All nodes listed below are leaf nodes, root node would be a branch node (for any non-negligible sized trie). Root hash is: keccak256(rlp(root_node))

Note - For the keys in the tries, I'm assuming that the HP-encoding doesn't factor into the paths, even though it appears in the node, BUT the node hashes (for leveldb) DO include the HP-encoding

**State Trie**

```
Key: keccak256(account address)
Value: rlp([nonce, balance, storageRoot, codeHash])
```

Where storageRoot is empty (so RLP-encoding presumably gives 0x80) and codeHash is keccak256("") for EOA.

**Transactions Trie**

Modified Merkle Patricia Tree rather than binary Merkel Tree for consistency rather than anything.

```
Key: rlp(index of where transaction is in block)  //how many bytes?
Value:      
      if legacyTx:
            value = rlp(tx)
      else:
            value = TxType | rlp(tx)
```

Where rlp(tx) is literally just the entire raw transaction (we could just use txid though)

**Receipts Trie**

```
Key: rlp(index of where transaction is in block)  //same as transactions trie
Value: 
        if legacyTx:
            value = rlp([status, cumulativeGasUsed, logsBloom, logs])
        else:
            value = TxType | rlp([status, cumulativeGasUsed, logsBloom, logs])
```

**Storage Trie**

```
Key: keccak256(storage slot integer 32 bytes)
Value: rlp(32 byte value in respective storage slot)
```